# How can I run redis on a single server on different ports?

Tags: redis, node-redis, kue

I'm using [kue](https://github.com/learnboost/kue) which uses [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis), but I'm also already using `node_redis` for my sessions, so I'd like to have `kue` create a server on a specific port say the default `6379` and then `kue` listen on port `1234`.

How would I be able to do this? I found [this article](http://chrislaskey.com/blog/342/running-multiple-redis-instances-on-the-same-server/) which talks about something similar, but I don't really want to have to create an init script to do this.

Comment: Have you ever considered simply putting them in different databases?  Redis default configuration has db 0 - 15.  I have production servers running a workflow manager in 1 DB while another DB handles sessions.  No need to run on 2 ports or run 2 instances. Being they are on the same machine it does not buy you anything to run 2 ports/instances.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Launch redis-server and supply a different argument for 'port' which can be done on the command-line:

```
edd@max:~$ redis-server -h
Usage: ./redis-server [/path/to/redis.conf] [options]
       ./redis-server - (read config from stdin)
       ./redis-server -v or --version
       ./redis-server -h or --help
       ./redis-server --test-memory <megabytes>

Examples:
       ./redis-server (run the server with default conf)
       ./redis-server /etc/redis/6379.conf
       ./redis-server --port 7777
       ./redis-server --port 7777 --slaveof 127.0.0.1 8888
       ./redis-server /etc/myredis.conf --loglevel verbose

Sentinel mode:
       ./redis-server /etc/sentinel.conf --sentinel
edd@max:~$
```

You can do this from, say, `/etc/rc.local` as well so that this happens at startup.

But maybe you can also rethink your approach. Redis is so good at handling writes that you may just get by with a second database?

Comment: Thanks for the post, it helped me to realize that I don't even need a config file. Side note:  I have a third party php script that uses flushall and wipes out all cache including my other application namespace. That's my reason to start another instance because flushall flushes all databases.

Comment: Please do refer here -> https://bencane.com/2013/11/12/installing-redis-and-setting-up-master-slave-replication/

Answer (score 2):

Very easy command:

`echo "port 4000" | redis-server -`

`echo "port 4001" | redis-server -`

Answer (score -1):

You can run multiple redis instance with different ports in a single machine.this concern is right mean you can follow the below steps.

> By installing the first Redis instance, It listens on localhost:6379 by default.

- For Second Instance
   create a new working directory

The default redis instance uses /var/lib/redis as its working directory, dumped memory content is saved under this directory with name dump.rdb if you did not change it manually.to avoid runtime conflict, we need to create a new working directory

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/redis2/
chown redis /var/lib/redis2/
chgrp redis /var/lib/redis2/
```

**Generate configurations**

Create a new configuration file by copying /etc/redis.conf

```
cp /etc/redis.conf /etc/redis2.conf
chown redis /etc/redis2.conf
```

**Edit following settings to avoid conflicts**

```
logfile "/var/log/redis/redis2.log"
dir "/var/lib/redis2"
pidfile "/var/run/redis/redis2.pid"
port 6380
```

**Create service file**

```
cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.service /usr/lib/systemd/system/redis2.service
```

Modify the settings under Service section

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis2.conf --daemonize no
ExecStop=/usr/bin/redis-shutdown redis2
```

**Set to start with boot**

```
      systemctl enable redis2
```

**Start 2nd redis**

```
service redis2 start


check status

lsof -i:6379
lsof -i:6380
```

> By Following this you can start two redis server.If you want more repeat the steps again.