# Running multiple instance of Redis on Centos

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, node-redis, redis-server

I want to run multiple instance of Redis on Centos 7.
Can anyone point me to proper link or post steps here.

I googled for the information but I didn't find any relevant information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run redis on a single server on different ports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600544/how-can-i-run-redis-on-a-single-server-on-different-ports)

Comment: my question is not duplicate

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can run multiple instances of Redis using different ports on a single machine. If this what concerns you then you can follow the below steps.

> By installing the first Redis instance, it listens on `localhost:6379` by default.

**For Second Instance create a new working directory**

The default Redis instance uses `/var/lib/redis` as its working directory, dumped memory content is saved under this directory with name `dump.rdb` if you did not change it. To avoid runtime conflicts, we need to create a new working directory.

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/redis2/
chown redis /var/lib/redis2/
chgrp redis /var/lib/redis2/
```

**Generate configurations**

Create a new configuration file by copying `/etc/redis/redis.conf`

```
cp /etc/redis/redis.conf /etc/redis/redis2.conf
chown redis /etc/redis/redis2.conf
```

**Edit following settings to avoid conflicts**

```
logfile "/var/log/redis/redis2.log"
dir "/var/lib/redis2"
pidfile "/var/run/redis/redis2.pid"
port 6380
```

**Create service file**

```
cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.service /usr/lib/systemd/system/redis2.service
```

Modify the settings under Service section

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis2.conf --daemonize no
ExecStop=/usr/bin/redis-shutdown redis2
```

**Set to start with boot**

```
systemctl enable redis2
```

**Start 2nd Redis**

```
service redis2 start
```

**Check Status**

```
lsof -i:6379
lsof -i:6380
```

> By Following this you can start two Redis servers. If you want more repeat the steps again.

Comment: Thanks a lot this helps

Comment: I have one more question. In section "Edit following settings to avoid conflicts" last line "add startup script". What does that mean?

Comment: When i run "service redis-6379 start" I get following message


Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  redis-6380.service
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to manage system services or units.
Authenticating as: Ashish K (ashish)
Password: XXX

               But redis server process is not there

Comment: Edit following settings to avoid conflicts means you need to set the separate log file,pid file ,datadir to new redis instance

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience Please don't consider '**add startup script**'
 I wrongly mentioned.

Comment: For your second question:  
      You need to change all tings in redis2.conf file.Need to mention separate files to each instance

Comment: Note that to start Redis with systemd, I would use `systemctl start redis` and not the sysv command as shown.

Answer (score 2):

If I set to `--daemonize no`, Redis will crash when data insert.

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis2.conf --daemonize no`

Should change to

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis2.conf` **--supervised systemd**

My Redis is 5.0.7.

FYI.

Comment: how does the "--daemonize no" change the equation?

Comment: @OAH You can follow the first comment step by step, and `vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/redis2.service` to chnage the equation.