# Multiple redis instances for multiple NodeJS servers

Tags: node.js, express, redis

After a bit of research, I came to the conclusion that I can run multiple instances of Redis on my CentOS server for each NodeJS server I run (I use Redis to store sessions).

I have followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352899/running-multiple-instance-of-redis-on-centos) and both instances are running properly on two different ports.

On my NodeJS servers, I configured Redis as follows:

```
import * as session from "express-session";

var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var redis = require("redis").createClient();

app.use(session(
    {
        secret: secret,
        store: new RedisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: redis }),
        cookie: { maxAge: 12 * 3600000 },
        resave: true, saveUninitialized: true
    }
));
```

One with port `6379` and the other with `6380`.

I use `req.session.regenerate` to register a session.

Both login systems work perfectly individually. However, when I load anything on one application, the sessions of the other application are deleted (and need to be re-logged in).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like it is the "session store" in Express and not your usage of Redis.

From the express session [documentation:](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

> NOTE be careful to generate unique IDs so your sessions do not conflict.

```
app.use(session({
  genid: function(req) {
    return genuuid() // use UUIDs for session IDs
  },
  secret: 'keyboard cat'
}))
```

**Name**: The name of the session ID cookie to set in the response (and read from in the request).

The default value is 'connect.sid'.

Specifically this warning explains your problem:

> Note if you have multiple apps running on the same hostname (this is
>   just the name, i.e. localhost or 127.0.0.1; different schemes and
>   ports do not name a different hostname), then you need to separate the
>   session cookies from each other. The simplest method is to simply set
>   different names per app.

Comment: I have tried to add: `genid:(req)=>{
            return uid.sync(18);
        }` to both applications without success

Comment: I don't understand your point since Redis stores sessions in two different databases... how would they interfere with each other?

Comment: I was thinking that your "user" was invalidating its login token due to running on the same hostname and key generating logic.

Comment: Got your point but I wrote that it disconnects ALL the sessions of the other application. The problem seems to be with Redis and how nodejs connects to it...but I can't figure out where the problem comes from. Thanks for your effort though!

Comment: Ah I see. That is very strange. If you want to send a link with a repo that I could run locally I can try and take a closer look.