# How do i make redis to populate two instances of one service in java?

Tags: elasticsearch, redis

We are upgrading elastic-search from 5.5 to 7.5 for that we want keep both 5.5 and 7.5 running so I want redis to populate two instances of a service at a time, how do i do that?

Comment: Please be clear what you are trying to acheive

Comment: I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352899/running-multiple-instance-of-redis-on-centos) will help you