# Multiple redis instances: opening the temp file needed for Master <-> Replica synchroniziation: Permission denied

Tags: redis, centos7, redis-server

I want to run multiple redis instances on one centOS 7 server. The instances are read-only replicas, which get synchronized from another server. I followed [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352899/running-multiple-instance-of-redis-on-centos) answer to get the second instance running.

At first I had a problem with not having the permissions on my used port 6380 for the second instance, but fixed that with `semanage port -a -t redis_port_t -p tcp 6380`.

The instance is starting and I can reach it but the database is empty. The replication should happen since it entirely depends on the config-file of redis. I get the following log through `systemctl status redis2 -l`

```
Apr 11 14:41:31 example redis[15831]: Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
Apr 11 14:41:31 example redis[15831]: Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)
Apr 11 14:41:31 example redis[15831]: Full resync from master: c7a4e046a533d04f71ac7c78ae2f16dac2126a85:7312794
Apr 11 14:41:36 example redis[15831]: Opening the temp file needed for MASTER <-> REPLICA synchronization: Permission denied
Apr 11 14:41:37 example redis[15831]: Connecting to MASTER xx.xxx.xx.xx:6379
Apr 11 14:41:37 example redis[15831]: MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
Apr 11 14:41:37 example redis[15831]: Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
Apr 11 14:41:37 example redis[15831]: Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
Apr 11 14:41:37 example redis[15831]: Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)
Apr 11 14:41:37 example redis[15831]: Full resync from master: c7a4e046a533d04f71ac7c78ae2f16dac2126a85:7312794
```

I think the important line here is `Apr 11 14:41:36 example redis[15831]: Opening the temp file needed for MASTER <-> REPLICA synchronization: Permission denied` hinting, that I'm missing a permission somewhere. All directories, which were covered in the answer I followed were triple checked and I can't find a wrong permission somewhere.

Did I miss something anywhere else? Does someone has experienced this and fixed it?